# How to change the version number and build number while updating an app in the Google Play Console?

Tags: flutter, google-play-console, android-update-app

This is the first time I am trying to build and release a mobile app (**Android**). I have used **[Flutter](https://flutter.dev/)** for developing the app.

After developing the app I have successfully released (internal-test-release) the app to [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/console). There were so many modifications carried into the app after releasing so I have to do multiple releases(internal-test-release), for each release I incremented the version value in **`pubspec.yml`**. Now the version value reached **`2.0.4+9`** from **`1.0.0+1`**.

Where **`2.0.4`** is the `version number` and **`9`** is the `build number` as per **[Flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#updating-the-apps-version-number)**

Every time I upload a release  I am not able to see an update option in the play store, I have to delete the app from the device and install it again. (*Expected to do an update of the existing app*)

I think the issue is with how I do the **`increment`** of the **`version number`** and **`build number`** in each release. So, how to change the **`version number`** and **`build number`** while updating an app in the Google play console, so that the installed app will show an update button in the play store.

This is how my current **`pubspec.yml`** `version` section looks like:
[image]

[ref-link](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning)

Comment: _Each time I do a release, as I am not able to see an update option in the play store, always I have to delete the app from the device and install it again._ It could be possible that you're seeing a cached page on Play Store. Or it could be due to a signature mismatch. You may have your debug APK installed on the device. In that case, the Play Store won't show updates for it. If that's the case, you can add applicationIdSuffix to your debug builds.

Comment: I also thought this `cached page on Play Store`, but after clearing cache also not fixed.

Comment: `Or it could be due to a signature mismatch` - Play. console wont allow to upload if it mismatches .

Comment: In the device I am testing, never installed the app directly from android studio for development purpose .

Comment: _Or it could be due to a signature mismatch_ a signature mismatch between debug and production builds. Is it possible that your app isn't reviewed by the Play Store?

Comment: In Google Play Console, in the all app section I can see that `app status`. is `in review`.

Comment: So once an app is reviewed by Play Store then only we will be able to see the update button?

Comment: yes. The update is available only after being reviewed.

Comment: Ohh! I never know of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the version number and build in your `pubspec.yamal`

Example `version: 1.0.0+1` to `version: 1.0.0+2`

**Step 1**:

Create a new release (in my case open testing the process should be the same for release mode also)

[image: Step 1]

**Step 2**:
Enter details and upload APP bundle

[image: Step 2]

App bundel
[image: App bundel]

**Step 3**:
Save => Review Release => Start roll out

[image]

**Step 4**: Wait till the review process is complete

Your app's update is uploaded and pending review.
[image: Step 4 review]

**Step 5**

After the review is done your users will update to the latest version of your app gradually. The update may take some time to reflect in the google play store.

**Note:**

1)In the above example version number is the same but the build number is different so it is treated as an update in the google play store. But it is highly recommended to change the version number also.

2)The example images provided are from open testing (beta) the process should be the same for the release version also.

Comment: So, next time if I upload a new bundle with an updated build number (with same version number) play store will show an update button?

Comment: Yes but I highly advise you to also change the version number also.

Comment: I have tried this and working for me. Some time play store is not showing the update button, I have to clear the storage of the play store and it's started showing up.
Thanks.

Comment: It does take some time to reflect the changes in all devices/users